# FindViewByID not working when using setID

Tags: java, android, xml, findviewbyid

I want to pro-grammatically create a <kbd>EditText</kbd> field and then make sure that the input is not null, I've been using setId to create an id for the fields and then use `findViewById(int)` but for some reason, I feel its not finding the Id.  Whenever I load the app on my phone, and I get to the "add" part, if i click it, it crashes.

Also, the `eweight.setText("TEST")` is to see if its setting the <kbd>EditText</kbd> to TEST which its not so I think I may be doing something wrong with the find ID/set ID?

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
EditText weight = new EditText(this);
EditText mark = new EditText(this);
mark.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
weight.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

weight.setId(99);
mark.setId(100);

layout.addView(mark);
layout.addView(weight);

AlertDialog.Builder addwork = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
addwork.setView(layout);

addwork.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        EditText eweight = (EditText) findViewById(99);
        EditText emark = (EditText) findViewById(100);
        String coursename = ecoursename.getText().toString();
        eweight.setText("TEST");

        try {
            if ((eweight.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) || 
                    (emark.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))) {
                throw new InvalidInputException();
            } else {
                // (irrelevant code removed)
            }
        } catch (InvalidInputException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast invalidinputtoast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please input a value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            invalidinputtoast.show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: did you tried layout.findViewById()

Comment: If you are creating the view dynamically. you can access it directly with the name assigned to it. No need of using findViewByID() here.

Comment: so EditText weight = (EditText) layout.findViewById(99);?

Comment: you written ecoursename.getText().toString(); but where `ecoursename` EditText is defined...

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
   EditText eweight = (EditText) findViewById(99);
   EditText emark = (EditText) findViewById(100);
```

with

```
  AlertDialog alertDialog = (AlertDialog)dialog;
  EditText eweight = (EditText) alertDialog.findViewById(99);
  EditText emark = (EditText) alertDialog.findViewById(100);
```

when you say `findViewById()`, it searches for the `View` in the `Activity` window and if you say `alertDialog.findViewById()`, it searches in `AlertDialog` window and here your layout is a part of `AlertDialog` window, not `Activity` window...

Answer (score 0):

Your findViewById() method giving null because it is finding the view in your activity layout but you have set the id on alertdialog layout so You should do this to run your code:--

```
 EditText eweight = (EditText) layout.findViewById(99);
 EditText emark = (EditText) layout.findViewById(100);
```

It works..!

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way 
 private EditText weight;
    private  EditText mark;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        weight = new EditText(this);
        mark = new EditText(this);
        mark.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        weight.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

        weight.setId(99);
        mark.setId(100);

        layout.addView(mark);
        layout.addView(weight);

        AlertDialog.Builder addwork = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        addwork.setView(layout);

        addwork.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String coursename = ecoursename.getText().toString();
                weight.setText("TEST");
                try {
                    if ((weight.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) ||
                            (mark.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))) {
                    } else {

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast invalidinputtoast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please input a value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    invalidinputtoast.show();
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you add view in alertDialog and so find id of edit text with respect to that view not in activity view .

```
 AlertDialog.Builder addwork = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
 addwork.setView(layout);
 addwork.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        EditText eweight = (EditText) addwork. findViewById(99);//changes here 
        EditText emark = (EditText)addwork.findViewById(100);
        String coursename = ecoursename.getText().toString();
        eweight.setText("TEST");


        try {
            if ((eweight.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) || 
                    (emark.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))) {
                throw new InvalidInputException();
            } else {
            (irrelevant code removed)


        } catch (InvalidInputException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast invalidinputtoast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please input a value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            invalidinputtoast.show();
        }
```